# Can I change a nested images background color on hover of parent div?

Tags: css, html, web, background-color

this is my first question on this website, hope someone can help me.

I have a parent div, which is a link to another page. There is a .png image within this div, and I want the background color of this png image to change when **I hover over the parent div, and not just the image itself.**

I want to do this in only HTML and CSS

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like, but the .png will need to be transparent to show the different background color

CSS:

```
#parent{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: green;
}
img{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
#parent:hover img{
    background-color:white;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <img src="something.png" alt="1" />
</div>
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Class/gWg3Y/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. I actually went and found the answer myself, and tried to post it, but as a new user I need to wait 8 hours before I can answer my own question :P Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to change img background using html css, if you want to the img background inherited from it's parent then use transparent background. welcome to SO !